# Iterating over string with whitespace

Tags: c, arrays, string, cryptography

I am currently coding a little rotation programm. But i have trouble with strings like "this is a test". When I have such a string it only encodes the first 4 characters instead of the whole string.. seems like the whitespaces are breaking something up. I tried to ignore the whitespaces with a if statement but this does not work and I don't know why. Do you have any idea for this problem?

And yes... the code is very experimental so please do not rage about const array sizes and such stuff..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define alphabetsize 26

char alphabet[alphabetsize] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',
                     'k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t',
                     'u','v','w','x','y','z'};
char lookup[alphabetsize] = {'0'};

char target[100] = {' '};

int search(char ch){
  int i = 0;
  for( ; i < alphabetsize; i++){
    if(alphabet[i] == ch) return i;
  }
}

char* rotate(char string[], int rotn){
  int i = 0;
  for( ; i < alphabetsize ; i++){
    lookup[rotn] = alphabet[i];
    rotn++;
    if(rotn == (alphabetsize)) rotn = 0;
  }
  i = 0;
  int index = 0;
  for( ; i < 100; i++){
    printf("%d\n", i );
    if(string[i] != ' '){
      index = search(string[i]);
      target[i] = lookup[index];
    }
  }
  printf("%s\n", target);
  return target;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int rotn = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);
  printf("String: %s\n", argv[1]);
  printf("Used Rotation degree: %d\n", rotn);
  char* string = rotate(argv[1], rotn);
  printf("Decrypted/Encrypted String: %s\n", string);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Spaces between program arguments end up causing them to be separate arguements... ie, `./progname this is a test` puts `this` in `argv[1]`, `is` in `argv[2]`, `a` in `argv[3]`, and `test` in `argv[4]` .  Try reading the line with `fgets()` or something like it in the program, and then processing it.

Comment: Nope I am starting the programm with: ./rot "this is a test" 13. "this is a test" is one argument.. not 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of your problem is in `search`, which fails to return a value if `ch` is not found in `alphabet`. In reality, this means it will return an unknown value, which you then use without any checks to index the `lookup` array.

Depending on the random contents of memory, you could be injecting spaces or `NUL` characters into your `target` array.

This actually gets triggered by your `rotate` function, which does not check for the presence a `NUL` in the input string and this does not terminate at the end of the string.

The test

```
   if(string[i] != ' ')
```

allows `search` to be called with the inevitable `NUL` in the input string. You then proceed to call search another eighty or so times with random values - most of which are unlikely to be in `'a'...'z'`

As soon as you invoke `search` with something other than a lower case character, your program is off into the world of undefined behavior.

Fnially, as @gaemaf has mentioned, your output index in the loop needs to be independent of the input index `i`. When you skip whitespace in the input, you also advance your output pointer (as you are using `i` for both).

The initialization `target[100] = {' '}` only initializes the first location of the array. The rest contains binary zero, which the `printf` in `main` interpets as end of string. Hence, even if you rotate the entire string, only the first word or so will get printed out.

To test, try it with an input string of "a bc def". I suspect you will only get one character printed out.

Comment: thats not part of my problem... When I have a whitespace character the `search` function will not be called cuz of the if statement. And I said its experimental code I know that somebody could inject some other stuff....

Comment: yes thx. I found the same reason for the problem a few minutes ago. the problem should be fixed now. I have initialized the array with whitespaces with `memset`.  Thx for mentioning the other problems.

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered your problem, so please try and let me know:

in the rotate function change your for:

```
int targetIndex = 0;
for (; i < 100; i++){
    printf("%d\n", i);
    if (string[i] != ' '){
        index = search(string[i]);
        target[targetIndex++] = lookup[index];
    }
}
```

Otherwise, because your target is initialized to NULL you will never see the full result.
To overcome your problem you need to add another variable like targetIndex.

Comment: This is also a problem, mind if I explain it a little more in my answer? The other problems also need to be fixed

Comment: @kdopen sorry but when I try to respond I do not have time to see what you or other are doing. For me, it is not a challange with you, I try only to keep up with my knowledge of C Language, nothing else. So what I understood from the question is where is the problem? I believe I found it. Ok it is not perfect answer. At the end if the community will cconsider my answer bad (downvote) I remove as like to say I apologize with all of you and read better your or other answer to improve my knoledge.  Thanks.

Comment: @kdopen perfect answer. In few moments I remove my answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yours was also a very good answer. You caught the "stops at first word" problem he was asking about ... I caught the problems he will have once he fixes yours :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't resolve your problem with your code, and is an example of code that will probably not get you a good grade due to its obfuscation, but you have to realize that 'rotN' type of problems are easily solved with modular math, if you understand the layout of the ASCII character set...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* rotate(char *s, int rotn)
{
  char *s1=s;
  for(;*s!='\0'; s++) if(isalpha(*s))
    *s = ((*s>'Z')?'a':'A')+(((*s-((*s>'Z')?'a':'A'))+rotn)%26);
  return s1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int rotn = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);
  printf("String: %s\n", argv[1]);
  printf("Used Rotation degree: %d\n", rotn);
  char* string = rotate(argv[1], rotn);
  printf("Decrypted/Encrypted String: %s\n", string);
  return 0;
}
```